# Why are my images Overlapping for Pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame, sprite

```
import pygame
import random
import os
import time

pygame.init()

#window and background
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,750))
pygame.display.set_caption("TD GaME")
background_img = pygame.image.load('best_backgroundv2.png')
background = pygame.transform.scale(background_img,(1000,750))

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, scale):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        img = pygame.image.load('Run/HeavyBandit_Run_0.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width() * scale), int(img.get_height() * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        
    def draw(self):
        win.blit(self.image, self.rect)

e_1 = Enemy(400, 500, 3)
```

So I am relatively new and trying to make a enemy(image) appear but is seems it has been overlapped by my background. I think it is due to how poor my code is in reference to setting the "background"

Comment: It appears that there is more code that needs to be shown to replicate the issue.  Please provide.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is missing the bit of code you have in your program that explains the order you are adding background and images to the window.  Lacking that, I came up with the additional code snippet that I added to the end of the code you included above.

```
while True:
    
    win.blit(background,(0, 0))         # Place the background into the window first
    e_1.draw()                  # Draw the bandit or other image(s) next
         
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

The takeaway here is the order in which the background and image are placed into the window.  In this sequence, I got the following screen.

[image: Sample Screen]

I didn't have your actual image files so I substituted some image files.  See if you can work with that.

Comment: I love you. Thanks